# How to traverse all subdirectories with sed and feed xgettext

Tags: sed, xgettext

I have this console command to make substitute in all PHP files in the directory. Then it feeds the xgettext program.

```
sed "s/\/\/_/_/g" *.php | xgettext -o output.pot --language=PHP - --from-code=UTF-8
```

How to change it so that sed traverse all PHP files in all subdirectories?

Comment: you use a tool like `find` or similar. sed can't do directory traversal on it's own

Comment: @FredrikPihl Yes, I have tried but with no success. Could you please write some code?

Comment: I could but what have you tried and what didn't work for you? :-)

Comment: @FredrikPihl 
I have tried for example this:
find ./ -type f -exec sed -i "s/\/\/_/_/g" *.php | xgettext -o output.pot --language=PHP - --from-code=UTF-8
I receive several errors (unable to find a file)

Comment: Try `find . -type f -name '*.php' -exec sed 's/python/perl/g' {} \;` use `-i.bak` to make the changes inline

Comment: @FredrikPihl Thank you, but what will be the command which feeds xgettext? `find . -type f -name *.php -exec sed "s/\/\/_/_/g" {} | xgettext -o output.pot --language=PHP - --from-code=UTF-8` ?